# Wider off canvas menu too wide to close on mobile

Tags: zurb-foundation

When changing the variable `$off-canvas-width` to a larger scale in `settings.scss` the off canvas menu successfully get's wider. But now the off canvas menu is too wide for mobile so the hamburger icon isn't available anymore. So it isn't possible to collapse close the menu again.

Is there a way to add a manual close button in the mobile menu which is only visible on mobile?

-or-

Is there a way to change the width of the sidebar per media query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your solutions should be able to be fixed via media queries..

**Button option**

*HTML*

```
<div class="nav">
<!-- Some stuff -->
<button>Close</button>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
@media screen only and (max-width:567px){
button{
display:block;
}

}

@media screen only and (min-width:568px){
button{
display:none;
}
}
```

**Sidebar width option**

*CSS*

```
@media screen only and (max-width:567px){
.nav{
width:100%;
}

}

@media screen only and (min-width:568px){
.nav{
max-width:300px; /*Or whatever yours is...*/
width:100%;
}
}
```